# Can I use my iMac as a display with my MacBook?

Tags: imac, display

Is it possible to attach my MacBook to my iMac and use the iMac as a display? What cable/connector would I need?

**EDIT:**

I have the newest MacBook and a Late 2009 21.5" iMac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which model of iMac do you have? Only the latest 27-inch model supports video in physically. There are software solutions if you don't have this model.

I'm not sure if this is the latest solution (I expect not), but it was a software solution to this problem. http://www.rutemoeller.com/mp/ibook/ibook_e.html

I'm sure I've seen something more recent than this, but can't find a link to it unfortunately.

**Update**: Found the software I was thinking of, the developers site is here: http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible with 27" iMac, but not sure about 21.5" one. The cable is "MagSafe connector".

Which iMac do you have ?

Please refer to Apple website for more info.

Comment: The MagSafe connector is for charging, it's nothing to do with sharing screens. The cable needed for the 27-inch iMac is Mini-DisplayPort cable. Usually you'll get an adapter for this into whatever video connect is available on your MacBook, which varies a lot model to model. Apple typically sells a good range of these adapters.

Comment: "MagSafe" is associated with the Apple power cables, none of the video cables.  The Apple LED Cinema Display has a split cable coming out of it with Mini DisplayPort and MagSafe.

Comment: Yeah, it's Mini Display port. I thought it's part of Magsafe connector cable, for both charging and connecting display b/n iMac and MacBook.

Comment: Nah, totally separate. They're just bundled together for neatness-sake in the latest Apple Display.

Comment: @Chops that's what I meant to say. If he buys this single cable, he can power his MacBook and also connect it to iMac.

Comment: @garikapati Yeah, fair enough, easy mistake to make. I think the only issue is that there isn't a cable you can buy like that. It comes as part of the new Apple Cinema Display built in. If you were to go into an Apple store and ask for a Magsafe cable, they'd sell you a charge for a laptop, which obviously isn't what's needed. I'm not aware of an integrated Magsafe, Mini-Display Port, USB combined cable that is sold as an individual item.