# Can I use my 2010 iMac as a display for my 2011 MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, display

My Belkin Mini DisplayPort to MiniDisplayPort cable has just arrived. I have the laptop plugged into the iMac. Everything is arranged the way I need it, except for one thing.

How can I cycle between using my actual iMac and the MBP? Sort of like expose to shift between desktops?

Comment: Whether you can do that depends on your iMac. Also, see: <http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5143/can-i-use-my-imac-as-a-display-with-my-macbook>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:
<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

I've connected my MacBook Air with my iMac, and it just works fine.

But you have no change to see the two devices at the same time.

Comment: You ARE a life saver! Thanks so much, this is perfect!!